# flask url function not working properly

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask

I have a an html form that is sending data with POST then I redirect to the same function using GET with the form data as arguments for the function

```
@app.route('/search/custom/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search_custom(category=None, date=None, page=None):

    if request.method == 'POST':
        category = request.form.get('InputCategory')
        date = request.form.get('InputDate')
        return redirect(url_for('search_custom', category=category, date=date, page=1))

    if request.method == 'GET':
        if not(category and date and page):
            return redirect(url_for('home'))

        flash('worked', 'success')
        return redirect(url_for('register'))
```

function is receiving the arguments correctly yet its only redirecting to "home":

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Apr/2018 01:55:36] "GET /search/custom/?category=Vetements&date=Dernier+mois&page=1 HTTP/1.1" 302 -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

category, date, and page are all None when processing a get request.

Inside of the Get handler, you'll need to actually pull the parameters from the query string.

Something like:

```
category = request.args.get('category')
date = request.args.get('date')
page = request.args.get('page')
```

should do the trick.

Put the before the check for the parameters and it should work.

I didn't have a chance to test this, so let me know if it doesn't work and I'll actually dig into it a bit more.

The way you have it now, you would probably want to have a formatted url for. Something like `/search/custom/<category>/<date>/<page>`. This would require changing the format of the incoming url too though, and that probably isn't what you want.

The code would look something like

```
@app.route('/search/custom/<category>/<date>/<page>', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@app.route('/search/custom/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def search_custom(category=None, date=None, page=None):
    # do stuff
```

Comment: thanks that worked ! and yeah I just want single url.